# How can i list all the functions in the class models using terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

from django.db import models

How can i list all the functions in the class models using terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to use the terminal, but this is how you can list all methods from `models` from your terminal:

```
python -c 'from django.db import models; print(dir(models))'
```

Answer (score 0):

In terminal type `dir(models)`
To get their apis try `help(models.<fx>)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dir` builtin function, quoting python docs:

> Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object. [1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)

An attribute can be class or instance variable, methods defined on that object class, or inherited from parent class.

So call

```py
dir(models)
```